# Do vibration motors vibrate in both directions at equal magnitude?

Tags: vibration-motor

I'm using two vibration motors for my robot and to have it move forward, I have to solder the leads of the motor in the way shown in the picture. Previously when I soldered the leads of both motors the same way, the robot kept turning round and round. Switching the leads of a motor helped solved that, but not completely.

I've noticed that the robot while moving straighter, tends to turn in favor of one direction over the other. This issue is even more apparent when the robot is supposed to turn in a direction responding to a light stimulus. I've noticed that the robot turns much quicker in one direction than the other.

I don't think it's an isolated case, I've assembled a few copies of the robots and all of them exhibit the same bias in turning toward a particular direction over the other. And the that bias is also in the same direction.

So I'm wondering for a vibration motor, do they vibrate the same if a voltage is applied to the leads and then that voltage polarity is reversed?

EDIT: [Link](http://www.vibration-motor.com/wp-content/themes/vibration-motors/dk-pdf/products/download/C1030B028F.pdf) to datasheet added

[image]

Comment: Assuming those are DC ERM vibrators, they'll spin in the opposite direction with the polarity reversed.  Are you using these to drive the robot, or is there another apparatus for moving it?

Comment: Can you add a link to the motor datasheet into your question?

Comment: @Transistor See edit

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Yes they do spin in the opposite direction as reversing the leads solved the problem of the robot just turning around in circles. What I'm wondering is if the spin is of the same magnitude, cause the robot seems biased to move in one direction after a while. Don't think it's a mechanical problem because the motors are placed at the same position on each side. The robot movement is enabled by bristle shaped legs underneath

Comment: Only the manufacturer or testing could answer this; brushed DC motors often do not perform the same in both directions, nor will two samples be identical.  But even if the vibration were *identical* motion achieved via a complex stick-slip interaction won't be equal.  For that matter, even two DC gear motors driving opposite wheels will not typically go straight.  You are going to need to plan a mechanism to compensate.

Comment: On your next iteration, put a gyro on your robot, and wrap the robot's direction with a feedback loop!

Comment: @TimWescott Does the feedback loop involve some kind of PID? How will the gyro help in feedback? Turns out this robot is way more complicated than I thought it to be...

Comment: I was being a bit tongue in cheek, but yes, you'd want some sort of a PID (or perhaps just PI) controller.  Control how much forward you want by the sum of the motor drives, and control how much turn you want with the difference -- and put that difference under PID control with the gyro as a reference.  Or, just have fun with what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC motors *can* turn faster in one direction than the other.  Basically, if the commutation is adjusted so that the brushes switch a bit sooner than the mechanically neutral position, the motor favors that direction.  ("Timing" DC motors used to be a hop-up trick for slot car racers, back when slot-car racing was a big thing).

Whether your motors *do* turn faster in one direction is based on the motor design and construction.  I could see a manufacturer doing that on purpose, if they had good enough process control (or I could see it happening by mistake, and persisting).